# How to fetch a task id in Alfresco Activiti

Tags: workflow, task, alfresco, bpmn, activiti

I need to know how to fetch the task id from within a BPMN process.
I tried the following without luck:

```
<serviceTask id="assignApplicationId" name="Assign Application Id" 
  activiti:expression="${sequenceUtil.getOutboundId(**task.id**)}" 
  activiti:resultVariable="OutboundWF_ApplicationNumber"/>
```

and

```
<serviceTask id="assignApplicationId" name="Assign Application Id" 
  activiti:expression="${sequenceUtil.getOutboundId(**bpm_taskid**)}" 
  activiti:resultVariable="OutboundWF_ApplicationNumber"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#apiExpressions), access to the `DelegateTask` only works for expressions evaluated in task listeners, so it does not seem to be possible to fetch the task ID with other expressions.